# How to append a string in a list if the word is NOT in the list, and not append it if it is in the list

Tags: append

I am new in python and I am stuck in creating a program.
The user need to input 5 words and if the user repeated the same word, that word will not be appended to the list. But if there's no same word, then it will print the 5 words.

```py
def store(list, word):
    
    list = []
    
    if word in list:
        list = list.append(word)
    else:
        list += word
        
        
    return (list,word)
```

Comment: You need to fix the formatting code. Presumably your teacher has told you how to accept input from the user (hint: run `pydoc input`) and how "for" loops work. You should also show us what happens when you run the code you've written and tell us which aspect of the program doesn't do what you expect or otherwise clarify what functionality is missing from your code

Answer (score 0):

This makes use of for loops and the `input()` function. First, we store an empty list. Then, we use `range()`, to have a for loop repeat 5 times, by asking the user to input a word. If the word is already in the wordlist, then we don't append it. Otherwise, we do. If you're only doing this action, there is no point in creating a function for it (you put `def store(list, word)` in your code), as it is not necessary for a simple task.

```
wordlist = []
for word in range(5):
    answer = input("Enter word: ")
    if answer not in wordlist:
        wordlist.append(answer)

print(wordlist)
```

I would recommend looking at some courses for how to do python, I am partly in agreement with @Kurtis Rader. Next time, when asking a question on SO, I also suggest that you tell us *what* errors you received when running the program, it lets us give better feedback.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gives me a clear explanation of it.